# Is it possible to walk from the UK/France to Georgia?

Tags: walking, france, england, georgia

I really want to go to the country of [Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(country)) but don't have enough money to fly there. I had a genius idea and decided that I could hire a boat and get across the English channel to France, and then walk from France to Georgia. If I walk for 12 hours a day, at a kilometer (approximately 1/2 mile) every 15 minutes, then I will get to Georgia in 84 days. (I worked it out!)

So I have two questions:

- Am I even allowed to waltz my way from France to Georgia?
- Are there any maps? Are there any maps to give me a route to Georgia?

I understand that you may think I'm just asking a silly question, but seriously, I want to know if I could walk to Georgia one day. I would need to make sure I have at least 1/3 of a year spare to do it though.

Comment: In general, you can walk across the border from one country to another, local laws permitting. You may need a visa in some cases, but that would be determined by your route and international treaties. But there's land all the way between France and Georgia. Sounds like a cool idea. For a faster trip, consider a bike.

Comment: This guy tried walking from Beijing to Germany: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ky6vgQfU24

Comment: The idea is great, but certainly not because it is cheap. Even if you camp every day, I am sure food alone will be more expensive than a cheap flight. Also this question might be too broad. There is the feasibility of your walking regime, country "visiting laws" and maps (which will vary from country to country again). Maybe it's worth splitting this up.

Comment: [Goran Kropp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6ran_Kropp) biked from Sweden to Everest, then climbed Everest without supplemental oxygen or Sherpa support, then biked back.  So you are in good company in your quest.

Comment: Daniel, when I first glanced at this, I thought you wanted to walk from Europe to the State of Georgia here in the USA!  Because you're not asking for something as crazy as that, and have done the research, I don't think it's a silly question at all. I do agree with @imsodin, though, that it might be worth splitting it up. There's an excellent answer already about the visa part, so asking the map one separately, with a link to this, might be a good idea.

Comment: Patrick Leigh Fermour did this more or less in the 1930's and wrote some great books about it...

Comment: I met a pilgrim who walked from Brittany to Jerusalem on foot in a spirit of deepening his faith. I suppose Georgia could also be done.

Comment: People have walked longer than that...
https://matadornetwork.com/bnt/seriously-slow-6-travelers-who-walked-around-the-world/

Comment: I really like the idea! Just wanted to mention that 48km on several days in a row seems a bit  ambitious to me. However, that strongly depends on your walking experience and overall fitness as well as external factors like luggage, weather, route etc.  So you might need more than 3 months

Comment: Yeah! I don't have a good walking experience (I've never been on an overnight walk) but I have very good fitness. You're right about many factors. @Marzipanherz

Comment: @imsodin:  I doubt that the cost of food would be a major factor, as the OP is going to be eating whether he goes or stays home.  Depending on his usual lifestyle, he might eat a bit more due to increased exercise, but not enough to matter.

Comment: that's 4500 km (via Turkey). That's a lot more than 84 days. I would count on at least twice that duration, especially given your lack of experience (general fitness is not all that is required to walk long distances)

Comment: Another factor.  Given your lack of money you might find yourself not admitted to places once you're out of the area where you have freedom of movement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're asking how to get from the UK to somewhere, I'll assume you're an UK citizen. Below you'll find a picture that shows your visa requirements.

[image]

You have two options: coming from above (crossing to Russia) and coming from below (crossing the whole Turkey). I'm pretty sure you'll pick the second choice, since Ukraine is at war and you'd need a rather expensive Russian visa if you chose the first one. Then, even if you choose to cross non-EU countries like Montenegro and Serbia, you'd only need to show your passport at a verification post, located in some specific cities (you necessarily have everything checked if you go by train of bus). It is very easy to cross without passing through a post, but I would never advise that. That's a crime and you can get easily caught when leaving the country.

Going from below you'd have to necessarily pass through Turkey (cross it, actually). [Here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_border_crossings_of_Turkey) of land borders in Turkey. You'd have to necessarily pass through one of them and have your passport stamped. As you saw in the visa requirements, you have the right to ask for an eVISA to Turkey, and I advise you to apply before you start your trip. You probably won't have any problems getting it, but remember: you can't stay in Turkey for longer than 3 months.

Then you're in Georgia. No visas required. Enjoy!

Comment: In the current state of affairs in Russia and Turkey, I would advice to take a ferry over the black sea. A friend of mine is cycling from Switzerland to Kirgistan and intends to follow the Danube, then cross to Georgia by ship for safety reasons.

Comment: I strongly support the premise above. Although Turkey is definitely not in the mud as Ukraine and that you wouldn't pass through the open war regions in the south, the situation there is bad enough to justify avoiding the place altogether

Comment: And another point not broached about the Russia-route: Russia and Georgia were in open conflict not too long ago. So entering Georgia from there could be problematic as well.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to get buses/trains to speed up the journey? They're cheaper than planes @QuantumBrick

Comment: That totally depends on what you're looking for. Busses in Eastern Europe are so extremely cheap (I went from Prague to Warsaw for one euro in a PolskiBus Christmas offer) that it might be a very good idea to take busses when you're crossing territory that offers nothing (like the Hungarian planes or a significant portion of Romania or continental Croatia). I really prefer to take busses around the Balkans, especially in countries like Montenegro and Bosnia are almost completely composed of mountains, and if you want to see them busses are the best (and cheapest) option.

Comment: Of course [Brexit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit) will change this (whenever that happens). There is a fair chance visa free access will be limited to UK citizens (and vice versa)

Comment: @Laim Are you sure? As far as I know Brexit doesn't touch Schengen laws, that is, citizens of the UK will still have the same visa requirements as, *e.g* Switzerland and Norway - that is, no requirements.

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of completeness I would like to add that flying might actually be the cheapest option for you.

While it sounds like an amazing adventure, walking takes a lot of time, and you still need to eat, at least sometimes you might want to sleep indoors, you might need to take a bus or a ferry every now and then. If I would have very little money, I would choose to hitch-hike, but I guess it is not for everyone.

Busses and trains could be cheaper for moderate distances, especially if there is a direct connection. But Georgia is not exactly close, and probably not that well connected to the UK. So you would need to change a few busses and trains on your way, which on its own could again be a great adventure, especially if you would stay longer in places. But maybe that's not what you are after.

Another option, which you haven't mentioned, would be using car sharing websites, such as blablacar. Some rides offered there are for pretty long distances. Could be worth checking it out if you absolutely want to go overland.

However it is hard to find any other means of public transport that would be as cheap as some of the flights offered. I have seen flights to Georgia for 30-50 Euros from places like Bukarest (Romania) or Vilnius (Lithuania). In case you do not have direct cheap flights from the UK, maybe you would be able to get to Lithuania, Romania or some other country with good connections cheap enough?

But yes, walk! Have an adventure of the lifetime! Only you really don't need to hire a boat, there already are ferries and a tunnel with a train.